# Jquery: reading buttons to select variables, adding and submitting them

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am having trouble making this work. this is bootstrap, and some custom jquery, but I'm a stone cold newbie, as I'm sure you'll see.

```
<form name="rolls" id="rolls">
<div style="height:6px;"></div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="die1" data-toggle="buttons" >
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked >1
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="2" autocomplete="off" >2
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="3" autocomplete="off" >3
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="4" autocomplete="off" >4
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="5" autocomplete="off" >5
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="die1" value="6" autocomplete="off" >6
                </label>
        </div>


<div style="height:12px;"></div>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="die2" data-toggle="buttons" >
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="1" autocomplete="off" >1

                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="2" autocomplete="off" >2
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="3" autocomplete="off" >3
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="4" autocomplete="off" >4
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="5" autocomplete="off" >5
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-info">
                    <input type="radio" name="die2" value="6" autocomplete="off" >6
                </label>
        </div>
```

```
<div style="height:12px;"></div>
    <span id="d1">D1</span> - + - <span id="d2">D2</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block " id="save"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> SAVE <span id="subtotal" ></span></button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rolls label').click(function() {
            var d1 = $(this).val();
            $(this).text(0);
            var d2 = $(this).val();
            var rollTotal = d1 + d2;
            $('#subtotal').text(rollTotal);
            /* how to submit these variables */
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The code is supposed to allow you to select the results of 2 dice, update the die fields to show the numbers selected, add them together and display the total on the submit bar, then submit the 3 variables (die1, die2, and rollTotal) when the submit is pushed. I can't seem to get it to work and stopped when I couldn't get the fields to update.

Answer (score 0):

[link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soluna668/9Lc7jjwL/9/)

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#die1 .btn').click(function() {
            var d1 = $(this).text();
            $('#d1').text(d1);
        });
        $('#die2 .btn').click(function() {
            var d2 = $(this).text();
            $('#d2').text(d2);
        });
            var rollTotal = $('#d1') +$('#d2');
            $('#subtotal').text(rollTotal);
            /* how to submit these variables */
    });
```

got the 2 fields updating, but can't make them add and update the button - which also bring me to the next hurdle, how to submit this info